# How can I access the photo library in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiimage

Is there any way to jump into photo library ? 
I'm not asking about `UIImagePicker`. 
In original camera app of iPhone, when I touch a thumbnail of one of the last photos (at the bottom left corner), it goes into photo library (actually, camera roll).
Is that private API or can i use it somehow? Well, I think I can implement that using ALAsset but I'm just wondering if there is any API

Comment: i may be misunderstanding what you want, but can't you just specify `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` for the UIImagePicker?

Comment: yes, you are misunderstanding my question. as i wrote, I'm not asking about imagepicker, but about launching photo album itself in my app (just like basic camera app in iPhone. it shows camera roll when you touch thumbnail of last photo)

Comment: Did you find a solution. I am also looking for a way to redirect user to the standard iphone Photo application (not for image picking, but just to open it). Mail application has its own URL link. Did you find it for photo app?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can launch the photo app, in order to view it as you would normally. However you cannot return to your app after launching the photo library.

You'll need to launch `com.apple.camera`

Comment: The camera app shows photo with something like modal, so i was looking for that way. Well, it must be private API. Thanks anyway.